# How do I join an event based table to produce a single record without duplicates

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `@Table1` that represents punches from a time clock. I am trying to join into a single record an `IN` punch with an `OUT` punch for a missing punches report. The problem is that each `OUT` record also produces a record of its own.

Technically the first punch is always an IN. If an employee forgets to punch in but DID punch out, we treat that OUT punch as IN and since the Out column is null in the query, it would be flagged as a missing punch.

There may be up to 8 punches total (lunch break and 2 smoke breaks).

I've tried replacing the left join with right joins and inner joins but had no luck getting my expected output.

SQL

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
                (
                    ScheduleId INT,
                    FileNumber INT,
                    TimeStamp  DATETIME
                )

INSERT INTO @Table1
VALUES (2080964, 14111, '2021-11-05 15:55:12.983'),
       (2080964, 14111, '2021-11-05 22:00:16.567'),
       (2080965, 14111, '2021-11-04 16:03:18.500'),
       (2080965, 14111, '2021-11-04 22:01:24.910'),
       (2080967, 14111, '2021-11-02 15:52:51.237'),
       (2080967, 14111, '2021-11-02 21:50:18.127'),
       (2080968, 14111, '2021-11-01 15:03:01.477'),
       (2080968, 14111, '2021-11-01 22:03:01.477'),
       --(2080974, 14111, '2021-11-06 15:55:32.427'), -- skiped to simulate a missing punch
       (2080974, 14111, '2021-11-06 22:00:50.437');


WITH CTE AS (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FileNumber, ScheduleId ORDER BY TimeStamp) AS PartitionOrder, *
             FROM @Table1)


SELECT *
FROM CTE AS PIn
         LEFT JOIN CTE AS POut
                   ON PIn.FileNumber = POut.FileNumber AND PIn.ScheduleId = POut.ScheduleId AND
                      PIn.PartitionOrder + 1 = POut.PartitionOrder
ORDER BY 4
```

### Current Output

| PartitionOrder | ScheduleId | FileNumber | TimeStamp | PartitionOrder | ScheduleId | FileNumber | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2080968 | 14111 | 2021-11-01 15:03:01.477 | 2 | 2080968 | 14111 | 2021-11-01 22:03:01.477 |
| 2 | 2080968 | 14111 | 2021-11-01 22:03:01.477 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 2080967 | 14111 | 2021-11-02 15:52:51.237 | 2 | 2080967 | 14111 | 2021-11-02 21:50:18.127 |
| 2 | 2080967 | 14111 | 2021-11-02 21:50:18.127 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 2080965 | 14111 | 2021-11-04 16:03:18.500 | 2 | 2080965 | 14111 | 2021-11-04 22:01:24.910 |
| 2 | 2080965 | 14111 | 2021-11-04 22:01:24.910 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 2080964 | 14111 | 2021-11-05 15:55:12.983 | 2 | 2080964 | 14111 | 2021-11-05 22:00:16.567 |
| 2 | 2080964 | 14111 | 2021-11-05 22:00:16.567 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 2080974 | 14111 | 2021-11-06 22:00:50.437 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

### Expected Output

| PartitionOrder | ScheduleId | FileNumber | TimeStamp | PartitionOrder | ScheduleId | FileNumber | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2080968 | 14111 | 2021-11-01 15:03:01.477 | 2 | 2080968 | 14111 | 2021-11-01 22:03:01.477 |
| 1 | 2080967 | 14111 | 2021-11-02 15:52:51.237 | 2 | 2080967 | 14111 | 2021-11-02 21:50:18.127 |
| 1 | 2080965 | 14111 | 2021-11-04 16:03:18.500 | 2 | 2080965 | 14111 | 2021-11-04 22:01:24.910 |
| 1 | 2080964 | 14111 | 2021-11-05 15:55:12.983 | 2 | 2080964 | 14111 | 2021-11-05 22:00:16.567 |
| 1 | 2080974 | 14111 | 2021-11-06 22:00:50.437 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Always a missing IN? I mean, how do you know if there is a missing IN or a missing OUT?

Comment: Well technically the first punch is always an IN. If an employee forgets to punch in but DID punch out, we treat that OUT punch as IN and since the Out column is null in the query, it would be flagged as a missing punch. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Are there always exactly one or two punches per `ScheduleId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking advantage of the DENSE_RANK, you can join rows where rank=1 with rows where rank=2, having both the same ScheduleId.

You can use either a LEFT JOIN: (Notice you always get a row with rank=1)

```
WITH ct AS
(
SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ScheduleId ORDER BY TimeStamp) dr
    , *
FROM
    @Table1
)
SELECT
    c1.ScheduleId, 
    c1.FileNumber,
    c1.TimeStamp AS Time_IN,
    c2.TimeStamp AS Time_OUT,
    IIF(c1.TimeStamp IS NULL OR c2.TimeStamp IS NULL, 'True', 'False') MissingTime
FROM
    ct c1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM ct WHERE dr=2) c2
    ON c2.ScheduleId = c1.ScheduleId
WHERE
    c1.dr = 1
```

Or an OUTER APPLY:

```
WITH ct AS
(
SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ScheduleId ORDER BY TimeStamp) dr
    , *
FROM
    @Table1
)
SELECT
    c1.ScheduleId, 
    c1.FileNumber,
    c1.TimeStamp AS Time_IN,
    c2.TimeStamp AS Time_OUT,
    IIF(c1.TimeStamp IS NULL OR c2.TimeStamp IS NULL, 'True', 'False') MissingTime
FROM
    ct c1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT ScheduleId, FileNumber, TimeStamp
             FROM ct 
             WHERE ScheduleId = c1.ScheduleId
                   AND dr = 2) c2
WHERE
    c1.dr = 1
```

| ScheduleId | FileNumber | Time_IN | Time_OUT | MissingTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2080964 | 14111 | 2021-11-05 15:55:12.983 | 2021-11-05 22:00:16.567 | False |
| 2080965 | 14111 | 2021-11-04 16:03:18.500 | 2021-11-04 22:01:24.910 | False |
| 2080967 | 14111 | 2021-11-02 15:52:51.237 | 2021-11-02 21:50:18.127 | False |
| 2080968 | 14111 | 2021-11-01 15:03:01.477 | 2021-11-01 22:03:01.477 | False |
| 2080974 | 14111 | 2021-11-06 22:00:50.437 | *null* | True |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=01f8458b3b4c6ada240092fd869f5643)*

Comment: almost perfect. the issue with hardcoding `rank=1` or `rank=2` is that there may be up to 8 punches total (lunch break and 2 smoke breaks). my question did not properly reflect that but it looks like the join subquery was the part i was missing.

Comment: You should state that in the question.